# Under what circumstances is a map of representation rings surjective?

Tags: algebraic-topology, representation-theory, lie-groups, topological-k-theory

Let $G > K$ be compact Lie groups. Then restriction of complex representations induces a homomorphism of representation rings $R(G) \to R(K)$.

**When is this map surjective?**

What conditions on the quotient $G/K$ guarantee it? What has been written on this?